# Bootstrap Modal Login & Signup Issue:

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make menubar consisting of menus names 'Login' & 'Sign Up' using bootstrap modalbox which consists of 2 tabs named 'Login' & 'Sign Up' using jquery. Refer the example given below.

Issues faced are:

1. When I first click on any of the menu in menubar, nothing is shown in modalbox under the 2 tabs. After clicking on any of the tab, content of tab is shown. I want that on first click also content of tabs is shown.
2. When I click on 'Login' menu, it's not like always 'Login' tab is opening & highlighting. Previously selected tab opens i.e. either 'Login' or 'Sign up' whichever was selected in previous attempt. Same is the case with 'Sign Up'. I want that when I click on 'Login' menu, tab 'Login' should open & highlight & when I click on 'Sign Up' menu, tab 'Sign Up' should open.

I'm a beginner & posting first time in stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance for your support!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#menu-top-right li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
  $("nav .nav-tabs li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');     
  $('nav .tab-content .tab-pane').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          
          
           <ul id="menu-top-right" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div role="tabpanel"> 
            
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#login" aria-controls="login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#signup" aria-controls="signup" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content" >
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="login">
                
                <div style="min-height: 150px; background: red;"></div>
                
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="signup">
                 <div style="min-height: 150px; background: blue;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should load your `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js` in the bottom of the `body` tag

Comment: jquery and bootstrap.min.js has already been loaded at the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#menu-top-right li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
        $(".nav-tabs li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');                  
        $('.tab-content .tab-pane').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />


    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>

  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">


           <ul id="menu-top-right" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div role="tabpanel"> 

            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#login" aria-controls="login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#signup" aria-controls="signup" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content" >
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="login">

                <div style="min-height: 150px; background: red;">text</div>

              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="signup">
                 <div style="min-height: 150px; background: blue;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#menu-top-right li').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
            $(".nav-tabs li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');                  
            $('.tab-content .tab-pane').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to you existing code ..

JS

```
$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myTab').parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('li:first-child,.tab-pane:first-child').addClass('active')   
})
```

**Assumption that `first-child` element is `login li tab` and `login div content` .**
If you have a class name `login` for both of them then you can use it like this

JS

```
$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myTab').parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.login').addClass('active')   
})
```